# What is a good source for learning Control Theory

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

I need to start learning and understanding Control Theory  for my research. Does anyone know good resources for doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Depending the on the level of mathematical sophistication you have you might try Eduardo Sontag's book. Here is a link to it.

http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~sontag/mct.html

Comment: The link is apparently dead. However, Eduardo Sontag has put a legal PDF copy online, that can be found here: http://www.sontaglab.org/publications.html

Comment: Thanks for the update.

Comment: For reference: To find the book, under "Selection by category" click on "Books and proceedings". It is then the sole entry from 1998.

Answer (score 0):

One of the classics for undergraduates just starting out is "Control System's Engineering" by Norman S. Nise.

I was introduced to intelligent control (applying machine-learning in control systems) from "Systems and Control" by Stanislaw H. Zak

Also, a classic on adaptive control is "Applied Nonlinear Control" by Slotine and Li. It also has a web component you can google.

I now plan on taking a step back and spending sometime with linear control, this is done well in "Mathematical Control Theory" by Sontag